# not able to export data from ArrayList To Excel cells correctly using Java

Tags: java, export-to-excel, poi-hssf

I want to export data from my 2d ArrayList as in the code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> bpDataAllLists = messtisch.getMeasDataBrushP();
    for (ArrayList<Double> bpDataList : bpDataAllLists) {
        int bp = ((bpDataAllLists.indexOf(bpDataList)) + 1);
        int measPerP = messtisch.getBpMeasPerPoint();

        HSSFWorkbook bprofileWb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet mainsheet = bprofileWb.createSheet("Meting");

        HSSFRow bprofileRow = mainsheet.createRow(5);
        HSSFCell bprofilecell = bprofileRow.createCell(3);
        time = messtisch.getMeastime();
        formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = formater.format(time.getTime());
        bprofilecell.setCellValue(date);

        int sCol = 7;
        for (int j = 1; j < measPerP + 1; j++) {
            // TODO create measperpoint colmn
            int sRow = 15;
            int bpPointsSize = bpDataList.size();
            for (int k = j - 1; k < bpPointsSize; k += measPerP) {
                bprofileRow = mainsheet.createRow(sRow);
                bprofilecell = bprofileRow.createCell(sCol);
                bprofilecell.setCellValue(bpDataList.get(k));
                System.out.printf("Row: %d, Column: %d, Value: %f\n",sRow,sCol, bpDataList.get(k));
                sRow+=1;
            }

            sCol+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

By print function, data is correct as follow:

Row: 15, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 16, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 17, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 18, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 19, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 20, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 21, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 22, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 23, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 24, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 25, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 26, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 27, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 28, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 29, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 30, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 31, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 32, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 33, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 34, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 35, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 36, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 37, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 38, Column: 7, Value: 12,000000

Row: 15, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 16, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 17, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 18, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 19, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 20, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 21, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 22, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 23, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 24, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 25, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 26, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 27, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 28, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 29, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 30, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 31, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 32, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 33, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 34, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 35, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 36, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 37, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 38, Column: 8, Value: 14,000000

Row: 15, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 16, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 17, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 18, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 19, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 20, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 21, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 22, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 23, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 24, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 25, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 26, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 27, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 28, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 29, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 30, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 31, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 32, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 33, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 34, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 35, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 36, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 37, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

Row: 38, Column: 9, Value: 16,000000

But in Excel export, I get this as shown in the picture [excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QURO1.png). I am not able to get, what I did wrong. Please help regarding.

Comment: Each iteration of the outer for loop creates a new `bprofileWb` and `mainsheet`.  Try moving to outside the loop.

Comment: I am trying to create separate workbook for each bpDataList, Is it wrong to do so?

Comment: A workbook represents the entire Excel file.  Do you really want multiple Excel files?

Comment: In one row I can set only one value if I set complete data row wise then it works.

Comment: @Andrew yes, I want separate Excel File.

Comment: The posted code doesn't show the workbook being saved to the file system. 
 For separate workbooks each iteration of the outer for loop would need to save the workbook.  You'll need a file naming convention so each iteration has it's own file name.

Comment: I tried to store them with diffrent name like: FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
       Messtisch.FOLDER_OUTPUT + "%s_%d_%s.xls", outFileName, bp, date));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time I was creating a row, a new row created and that overwritten the previous data. So I needed to create row only once. If the row exists then write in the same row.

By using this method:

```
 private HSSFRow getRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum) {
 HSSFRow sheetRow = null;
 sheetRow = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
  if (null == sheetRow) {
    sheetRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
 }  
 return sheetRow;
 }
```

So now, I changed `mainsheet.createRow(sRow);` with `getRow(mainsheet, sRow);`
It worked.